# How to show specific category as list instead of grid in listing pages?

Tags: category, magento2.4.5, list.phtml

My default view Mode in the Listing pages is grid, I want for a specific category (including sub-categories ) to be displayed as List

Answer (score 0):

*You need to set **$viewMode** , **$imageDisplayArea** , **$showDescription** and **$templateType** as per your requirement in this file*

*You can see magento condition in around **line no. 31***

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```